# Difeomorphism group

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, solution-verification

**Definition.** *If $U$ and $V$ are open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, a differentiable homeomorphic  $h\colon U\longrightarrow V$ with inverse $h^{-1}\colon V\longrightarrow U$, is called diffeomorphism.*

I want to verify that the set of difeomorphism is a group under composition. It sounds a bit trivial however I would like to know if it is okay.

- If $f\colon U\to V$ and $g\colon V\to W$ are diffeomorphism, since the composition of homomorphisms is a homemorphism, then $g\circ f\colon U\to W$ is differentiable homeomorphism, and since there exist $f^{-1}:V\to U$ and $g^{-1}\colon W\to V$ then $(g\circ f)^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$, hence $g\circ f$ is diffeomorphic.
- The associative property is showed analogously to the previous one.
- Let $1_{U}\colon U\to U$ the identity difeomorphism, such that $f\circ 1_{U}=1_{U}\circ f=f$.
- To guarantee the inverse of a difeomorphism is a difeomorphism, I have a little doubt, I think it is because of the inverse function theorem.

Comment: How are you defining the composition $g \circ f$ if the image of $f$ is not necessarily a subset of the domain of $g$?

Comment: The diffeomorphisms of arbitrary open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ certainly do *not* form a group: given $f:U_1\to V_1$ and $g:U_2\to V_2$, the composition $f\circ g$ is not well defined unless $U_1\subseteq  V_2$. Further, it will not be invertible unless $U_1=V_2$.

Comment: Diffeomorphisms from $U$ to itself do form a group, while diffeomorphisms between arbitrary open sets of $\mathbb R^n$ form a [groupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments have indicated, you need to make sure you're talking about maps $U \longrightarrow U$ so they can always be composed, lest you want to deal with a groupoid. However, I'd also like to point out that your definition of a diffeomorphism is wrong, which is why you were having trouble with inverting diffeomorphisms. A diffeomorphism is a differentiable bijection with differentiable inverse, so the inverse of a diffeomorphism is a diffeomorphism by definition. Under your definition, this is not true. Take $f: \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ via $f(x)=x^3$. This is a smooth homeomorphism but its inverse is not differentiable at $0$, so your definition is not closed under inverses.

Comment: Thank you very much, if the definition was wrong, you are reading a book and it says consider the germ diffeomorphism group $f\colon (\mathbb{R}^n,0)\to(\mathbb{R}^{n},0)$, I would try this as I indicated before.

Comment: @JulianBejarano Glad to help! And by the way, if you're dealing with germs of differentiable functions then you do include those represented by $f: U \longrightarrow V$, so long as $U, V$ both contain $0$.

Comment: How would the composition of two germs of difeomorphisms be defined in that?

Comment: @JulianBejarano My apologies, I think I missed something so this is wrong, but here was the idea. I presume your definition of a germ is that $f \sim g$ if they have the same restriction in some neighborhood of $0$. If we had $f: U \longrightarrow V$ and $g: W \longrightarrow O$ where these are all neighborhoods of $0$. Then these represent germs $[f], [g]$. The composition $[f] \circ [g]$ can be represented by $f|_{O \cap U} \circ g|_{g^{-1}[O \cap U]}$. This is all fine, but the issue I'm having is that this preimage need not be a neighborhood of $0$ as $g$ need not send $0 \mapsto 0$.